# What is the issue with my code ?

Tags: javascript, syntax

At the moment I'm studying functions, and I cannot really find out what's wrong with the following code.
No matter what value "password" takes I always get "NICE"

```
var passValid = function (password) {
    return password.length;
};

if (passValid<5){
    console.log("ERROR");
}
else{
    console.log("NICE");
}

passValid("somevalue");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
if (passValid("password") < 5) {
  console.log("ERROR");
}
else {
  console.log("NICE");
}
```

I'm not sure how to describe why your original code is wrong; it's just sort-of off in the weeds :-)

Answer (score 2):

you are missing argument in function call

```
if (passValid<5)//no argument
if (passValid("passowrd")<5)//pass an argument
passValid("somevalue");//no need for this
```

or

```
var passValid = function (password) {
    //return password.length;remove this from here
//}; remove this from here

if (password.length<5){
    console.log("ERROR");
}
else{
    console.log("NICE");
}
}; //add here so now entire is function
passValid("somevalue");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't call the function, but try to compare the function itself with a number instead of using the value returned by that function.

In your case `passValid` is just a reference to the function. For a value to be returned you must issue a call to it by using `passValid( "someValueInHere" );`

Try this instead:

```
var passValid = function (password) {
  return password.length;
};

if ( passValid("somevalue") < 5){
  console.log("ERROR");
} else {
  console.log("NICE");
}
```